# File changes not updating in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

I recently installed TensorFlow on my mac with the recommended settings [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac). If I save changes to a .py file, I have to deactivate/activate in order to see them when I run the code.

Why this is happening, and is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

1. Go to the directory where your code is saved.
2. *Then* run `source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate`